# Facebook API - call returns less fields when using access token

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook4j

I have public page post id, about which I would like to get more data. When I make API call like this,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{POST-ID}
```

I get back full data about the page post including comments, link, attached photo etc. However, when I try to make the call with callGetAPI in facebook4j library, it always adds my access token to the end of the url, so it becomes

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{POST-ID}?access_token={TOKEN}
```

And with this call I get back only three fields: created_time, message and id (which is {POST-ID} again). Why it is like that? I get less data with valid access token than without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a feature that came with v2.4 of the Graph API: "Declarative Fields". Try with the Access Token of an older App and you may get the same result. Although, it looks like a bug when not using an Access Token.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4